Merge the [typeinitializeexception] and [typeinitializationexception] tags, possibly also [typeinitializer]
typeinitializeexception and typeinitializationexception are about the same .NET exception.
typeinitializer is mostly about that same .NET exception, but there are a few Java-related questions in there too.

I merged typeinitializeexception into typeinitializationexception since TypeInitializationException seems to be the correct spelling of this exception and they do, indeed refer to the same concept.
The majority of the questions tagged typeinitializeexception have it spelled correctly in the title or the body, so I'm unsure how this tag ended up being the more prevalent tag.
Regardless, the tags are now merged and synonymised
updating post history, 54 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 45 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 44 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'typeinitializeexception': [typeinitializeexception] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 52
tag remapping of [typeinitializationexception] and [typeinitializeexception] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!


I did not merge typeinitializer because it appears to represent a different concept (or at least it can). There are a few questions about initialization in general that don't deal with the exception. Given the distinct usage, in addition to the usage across languages, it's not, in my opinion, a good merge or synonym candidate at this time. If it should be part of this group it would need to undergo a disambiguation first before being merged.
